# Fluent NHibernate Cascade vs Inverse confusion

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, cascade, inverse

I know this has been discussed countless number of times , but I am yet to get my head around this. The question is : when to use Inverse and when to use Cascade on a Many-to-Many.

Here's my scenario :

I have two entities:

```
 public class Contact
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }

 public class Employee
 {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
 }
```

And here are their maps:

```
 public class ContactMap : ClassMap<Contact>
    {
        public ContactMap()
        {
            Table("Contact");
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);

            HasManyToMany(x => x.Employees)
               .Table("Contact_Employee_Link")
               .ParentKeyColumn("Contact_Id ")
               .ChildKeyColumn("Employee_Id")
               .AsSet();
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Name);

            HasManyToMany(x => x.Contacts)
                .Table("Contact_Employee_Link")
                .ParentKeyColumn("Employee_Id")
                .ChildKeyColumn("Contact_Id")
                .AsSet();
        }
    }
```

The Contact_Employee_Link table just has two columns : Contact_Id and Employee_Id ..both
   are foreign keys to respective primary key tables.

I have written a (ridiculous) unit test to test the working :

```
       [Test]
    public void ShouldSaveEmployeeLinksWhileSavingContact()
    {
        Employee employeeAlias = null;
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var contact = session.QueryOver<Contact>()
                 .JoinAlias(x => x.Employees, () => employeeAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                .Where(x => x.Id == 9)
                 .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                .SingleOrDefault();

            var employee = session.QueryOver<Employee>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
                .SingleOrDefault();

            contact.Name = "BNM";
            contact.Employees.Add(employee);
            session.SaveOrUpdate(contact);
            session.Flush();
        }

        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {

            var contact = session.QueryOver<Contact>()
                .JoinAlias(x => x.Employees , () => employeeAlias , JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                .Where(x => x.Id == 9)
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                .SingleOrDefault();

            Assert.That(contact.Employees.Count == 1);
        }
    }
```

And it works perfectly well.No extra updates , nothing wrong ..works like a charm.
I have neither used Cascade.SaveUpdate() neither Inverse ..and it still works fine.

I have another similar test which adds contacts to an employee object and that works perfectly fine too.

Even if I set Cascade.SaveUpdate() on both the Many-to-Many mappins , it still works
perfectly fine.

I then tried setting one end of the mapping as Inverse ( along with both set as Cascade.SaveUpdate() ) and it still works perfectly fine.

My aim is to understand whats the best way to model a bi-directional many-to-many relationship . It seems to be working with what I have got .. but I can't understand why it works .

I do understand that "Inverse" signifies which end of the relationship owns the relation.

How does that apply to a Many-to-Many ?

And what if I need to be able to add from both ends ..should I just use Cascade.SaveUpdate then ..or not use anything like what I have done right now ?

Any ideas ...??
Can someone explain why my unit test works ?

Thanks

Comment: Any ideas .. anyone ??